# implementing condition on Maximum occurance of an element in XSD depending on its elements

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am working some schema creation.

My schema structure looks like this.

Schema 1(Embedded schema):
    It has two fields:
        1.select:Drop Down to allow two values "Heading" and "Title"
        2.text

Schema 2:
   It has following fields;

```
    1.First--of Type Schema 1: As a field. Max occurrence is 4
```

The source of main schema looks like this:

```
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:tcmi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance"></xsd:import>
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <tcm:Labels xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                <tcm:Label ElementName="select" Metadata="false">select</tcm:Label>
                <tcm:Label ElementName="text" Metadata="false">text</tcm:Label>
            </tcm:Labels>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType name="Content">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="select" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:appinfo>
                        <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
                        <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">1</tcm:Size>
                        <tcm:listtype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">select</tcm:listtype>
                    </xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Heading"></xsd:enumeration>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Title"></xsd:enumeration>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="text" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="tcmi:MultiLineText">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:appinfo>
                        <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
                        <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">2</tcm:Size>
                    </xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

This schema is referred in the main schema as "Field"--First

```
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="some name space" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="some name space" xmlns:tcmi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance">
                    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance" schemaLocation="location.xsd"></xsd:import>
                    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Schema 1 location"></xsd:include>
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo>
                            <tcm:Labels xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                                <tcm:Label ElementName="First" Metadata="false">First</tcm:Label>
                            </tcm:Labels>
                        </xsd:appinfo>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:element name="Content">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="First" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4" type="Content">
                                    <xsd:annotation>
                                        <xsd:appinfo>
                                            <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
                                            <tcm:EmbeddedSchema xlink:href="Schema 1 location" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xlink:title="abcd"></tcm:EmbeddedSchema>
                                        </xsd:appinfo>
                                    </xsd:annotation>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:schema>
```

The field "First" is following Schema 1. So In turn It has 2 fields.
My need is as No Of occurrence of the Field "First" is 4. I also want to apply one more condition it.

The Conditions:

```
    1.No Of occurrence of the "First" is 4.
    2. As Schema 1 has drop down to select values "Heading" and "Title".
        I want to restrict that out of 4 occurrence of "First", 
        Heading can occur Maximum  2 times and Title can occur maximum of 2 two times.
```

Can any one help how to achieve this.